# Cloud hosting for JavaEE, that charges per CPU cycle

Tags: jakarta-ee, hosting, cloud

I have a JavaEE web-service project which I normally deploy on Glassfish, that I wish to host online. It has high memory requirements (4GB) but very low CPU utilization, and it is not very frequently accessed as a web service. Hence, I just want it to be there, idle, listening for requests, and pay something reasonable, based on its CPU utilization.

So far, the only hosts that I have found are:
Google App engine - but does not support JavaEE, hence I need to re-factor my project
selectel.com/services/cloud/ - they suspended the service since 14.10.2011

any other that do not charge idle CPU time and allow virtual machine instantiation or JavaEE container?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try http://jelastic.com.
It's beta now, but I used it and it's really works!

Comment: Nice site, but does not support JavaEE, only tomcat.